# Out of Memory error finding products and primes

Tags: c#, recursion, methods, out-of-memory

So I wrote a quick app to check my son's homework and it appears to be working fine.  It takes a number, finds all the primes, then finds all the product combinations.  So, for example, you pass it "210", and it will return:
2 x 3 x 5 x 7
5 x 6 x 7
7 x 30
6 x 35
5 x 42
3 x 7 x 10
10 x 21
3 x 70
3 x 5 x 14
14 x 15
2 x 7 x 15
2 x 105
2 x 5 x 21
2 x 3 x 35

The problem I'm having is when doing large numbers.  It will handle 256 (2^8) after only a moment's hesitation, but when I do 512 (2^9), I get a OutOfMemoryException.  Can someone recommend a better way of finding the product sets?  My code is below.

```
class Program
{
    private static List<List<int>> coll = new List<List<int>>();

    public static List<int> PrimeFactors(int i)
    {
        if (i < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Numbers less than 2 don't have prime factors");
        }

        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        int divisor = 2;

        while (divisor <= i)
        {
            if (i % divisor == 0)
            {
                result.Add(divisor);
                i /= divisor;
            }
            else
            {
                divisor++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void GetFactors(List<int> l)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int x = i + 1; x < l.Count; x++)
            {
                List<int> loopList = new List<int>(l);
                int newProd = l[i] * l[x];
                loopList.RemoveAt(i);
                loopList.RemoveAt(x-1);
                loopList.Add(newProd);
                loopList.Sort();
                coll.Add(loopList);
                if (loopList.Count > 2)
                {
                    GetFactors(loopList);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int target = Convert.ToInt16(args[0]);
        List<int> results = PrimeFactors(target);
        results.Sort();
        coll.Add(results);
        GetFactors(results);
        List<string> factors = new List<string>();
        foreach (List<int> lst in coll)
        {
            string listString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == lst.Count - 1)
                {
                    listString += String.Format("{0}", lst[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    listString += String.Format("{0} x ", lst[i]);
                }
            }
            factors.Add(listString);
        }

        foreach (String factorString in factors.Select(x => x).Distinct())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(factorString);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  Here is the new code, based on answers below.  Works for any Int16 I throw at it.

```
    class Program
{
    private static List<List<int>> coll = new List<List<int>>();

    public static List<int> PrimeFactors(int i)
    {
        if (i < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Numbers less than 2 don't have prime factors");
        }

        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        int divisor = 2;

        while (divisor <= i)
        {
            if (i % divisor == 0)
            {
                result.Add(divisor);
                i /= divisor;
            }
            else
            {
                divisor++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void GetFactors(List<int> l)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int x = i + 1; x < l.Count; x++)
            {
                List<int> loopList = new List<int>(l);
                int newProd = l[i] * l[x];
                loopList.RemoveAt(i);
                loopList.RemoveAt(x-1);
                loopList.Add(newProd);
                bool existsInCollection = false;
                foreach (List<int> existingList in coll)
                {
                    if (ListEquality(existingList, loopList))
                    {
                        existsInCollection = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!existsInCollection)
                {
                    coll.Add(loopList);
                    if (loopList.Count > 2)
                    {
                        GetFactors(loopList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool ListEquality(List<int> listA, List<int> listB)
    {
        if (listA.Count != listB.Count)
            return false;

        listA.Sort();
        listB.Sort();

        for (int idx = 0; idx < listA.Count; idx++)
        {
            if (listA[idx] != listB[idx])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int target = Convert.ToInt16(args[0]);
        List<int> results = PrimeFactors(target);
        results.Sort();
        coll.Add(results);
        GetFactors(results);
        foreach (List<int> lst in coll)
        {
            string listString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == lst.Count - 1)
                {
                    listString += String.Format("{0}", lst[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    listString += String.Format("{0} x ", lst[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(listString);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: I ran this in the debugger with an argument of 512, and after letting it run for a bit, I manually broke in. `col1` had some 29 million entries, so there's definitely an infinite loop logic bug in there...

Comment: You can also optimize this be starting at the square root of the number you're factoring and work down.

Comment: Mike: Don't think it's an infinite loop error, as there are 2.2 million entries for 256, rather it's an issue of how many ways are there to combine eight 2's.  Trying to implement Hogan's solution below to not add to the collection if it already exists, but my LINQ comparer does not seem to be working correctly.

Nathan: Thanks, but the prime factoring part is sufficiently fast, it's the product sets that are dragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things that could be better with this program.

Here are a few:

- Don't use a global (`coll`)
- Don't use bad variable names (`i`,`l`,`x`)
- Don't use `List<int>` when `int []` would work as well or better.
- Use `join` to print out your list.

Some things that would make this program faster

- Don't recurse, iterate.  (Hint - an abstract stack object or abstract set object would help.)
- Don't sort so much, should not matter and in fact might slow you down.
- Prune your temporary storage as you go -- waiting till the end to do the distinct just means you have done **WAY TO MANY** of the same thing multiple times.  Before you add it to the collection check if it is already there.

Comment: This is for personal use only, bad variables and such are irrelevant.  Also, I'm not aware that arrays are "better" than generics.  The sorting was to determine the Distinct.  I was not getting a correct result finding Distinct values of the List<int>, even after sorting. I will, however, try iterating and see what results.  I think adding logic to find distinct values before the fact may involve more effort than I'm willing to put into a simple homework solver, but I appreciate the feedback.  Thx.

Comment: Are they?  If a program would be clearer to others then it will also be clearer to yourself.  Also, globals are bad for other reasons as are inappropriate data structures.  The best data structure is different as I will show above.

Comment: Never mind my comment about showing you the better data structure, given the edit to your comment you don't actually care to solve this program well.

Comment: Ok, as is your prerogative.  You're right in that I don't plan to spend hours tweaking this for the best performance, nor am I overly concerned about my variables not making sense.  Again, this is a use once and throw away solution.  That doesn't take away, however, from the usefulness of your other comments that are not related to semantics.  I of course welcome any feedback, I just thought I should make it clear that my question was of a logical nature, not a syntactical one.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hogan: Your last suggestion nailed it.  Did a compare against the collection before adding and continuing on, and it now returns "512" in less than a second.  Anyone know how I can include that code for people to reference in the future?  Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: @Slightly A.: you should be able to edit (the link should be somewhere between the bottom of the question and above the first comment) your original question and change the code.